# Is there a term for "-tive" and "-tative" word pairs ?

Tags: terminology

- preventive and preventative
- interpretive and interpretative
- exploitive and exploitative
- authoritive and authoritative

Is there a term, grammatical or not, for these pairs?

Comment: *Authoritive* is not listed in the OED even as an alternate form for *authoritative,* and its [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=authoritive%2C+authoritative&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows strictly negligible comparative (comparive?) frequency. As for the other pairs, which of the altern[at]ives are you saying is newer and once dismissed as fad? Per Ngram, *interpretive* seems to have surpassed the formerly favored interpretative in 1963, but *preventive* seems always to have had the edge over *preventative, exploitative* over *exploitive.*

Comment: Exploitative vs exploitive: http://grammarist.com/spelling/exploitative-exploitive/

Comment: Some of your examples are incorrect. I know your question, but can you come up with actual, real-life, used-in-writing-not-blogging examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a single pair seems adequate to illustrate the general principle here.

***Interpretive*** was [a late starter](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interpretive%2Cinterpretative&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterpretive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterpretative%3B%2Cc0), and etymologically speaking it stands on somewhat shaky ground. The originally "standard" version ***interpretative*** derives from *Latin **interpretāt-**, participial stem of **interpretārī*** (i.e. - there were always two **t**'s even in Latin).

OED says under its entry for the more recent ***interpretive*** that it's modeled on forms such as ***assertive*** - from *Latin **assert-** participial stem of **as-serĕre*** (only *one* **t** in the Latin original).

I assume no-one really wants to defend ***assertative, assertitive***, or (God forbid! :) ***assertatitive*** too strongly. Usually if people are going to bend the rules they at least want the justification of being able to say theirs is a *shorter, simpler* form.

---

I'm a descriptivist by nature, so I'm not going to say any of the "non-standard etymology" versions of such word-pairs are actually *wrong*. But you could say they're examples of...

> [**back-formation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation)
>   *the process of creating a new lexeme, usually by removing actual or supposed affixes*

I think it's still back-formation if you *add* rather than *remove* an affix. But as implied above, such variants aren't so likely to catch on anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Another term I would use for these pairs is ***variants***. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/variant

I believe ***doublet*** from @Erik Kowal is more precise.